# При вводе текста, бот работает, но потом он все время повторяет и высылает этот текст. Как это исправить?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client();

const TOKEN = 'токен';

bot.on('ready', () => {
  console.log('The bot successfully started!');
});

bot.on('message', (message) => {
  if(message.content == '!help') {
    message.reply(
      `Список команд: \'!knowavatar\', \'!help\'`,
      `Список команд буде оновлюватися!`
    );
  }
});

bot.on('message', (message) => {
  if(message.content == '!knowavatar') {
    message.reply(
      `Аватар ${
        message.author
      } виглядає так -> ${message.author.displayAvatarURL()}`
    );
  }
});

bot.on('message', (message) => {
  if (message.content !== '!knowavatar' && message.content !== '!help') {
    message.reply(`Ти ввів: ${message.content}.`);
  }
});

bot.login(TOKEN);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас бот реагирует на сообщение самого себя. Добавьте проверку что message.author.bot != true.